# ngrx: go to url only when LoggedInAction has happened

Tags: angular, ngrx, resolve

I have this problem where I have to wait until my token is returned for my authentication-server before calling my apis, I was wondering if there is a nice way to wait until my authState.token is something other than null before dispatching LoadMyStuffFromApi.

I have two resolvers:

LoginResolver:

```
public resolve(route: Activate...): Observable<Action> {
    this.store.dispatch(new LoginAction());
    return this.actions$.ofType(LOGGED_IN_ACTION).take(1);
}
```

MyDataLoadedResolver:

```
public resolve(route: Activate...): Observable<Action> {
    this.store.dispatch(new LoadDataAction());
    return this.actions$.ofType(DATA_LOADED_ACTION).take(1);
}
```

my router then has

```
{
    path: ':caseId',
    component: CaseViewerComponent,
    resolve: { login: LoginResolver, loadCase: MyDataLoadedResolver}
}
```

Is there a way for me to wait until the login resolver is done before doing the loadCase resolver, or would you do this differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the store you could set a default valued variable called loggedIn = false. In the place that you are making the API calls you can subscribe to changes on loggedIn and only run them once loggedIn becomes true

Comment: Thank you! This is what I ended up doing :)